# R: How can I pivot a single row into a column?

Tags: r, pivot

I think I understand the basics of the dplyr pivot_longer() and pivot_wider() functions, but now I have a messy data table (originally in excel):

```
reprex <- tibble(
  Sample = c("Colour","A","B"),
  cells1green = c("green","3917","4370"),
  cells1red = c("red","267","299"),
  cells2green = c("green","4443","7082"),
  cells2red = c("red","1438","1694"))
```

In excel, Columns 2 & 3 are both named cells1 and Columns 4 & 5 are both named cells2. I added "green" and "red" to the names as R changes the name of a duplicate column name anyway. I'm wondering if there is a way to turn just the first data row ("green","red","green","red") into a column ("Colour") and fuse the cells1... columns into one column and the cells2... columns into one column. The last step would be to pivot_longer to eventually have this table:

```
reprex_final <- tibble(
    Sample = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B"),
    Celltype = c("Cells1","Cells1","Cells2","Cells2","Cells1","Cells1","Cells2","Cells2"),
    Colour = c("green","red","green","red","green","red","green","red"),
    Signal = c(3917,267,4443,1438,4370,299,7082,1694))
```

Maybe somebody has an idea about how to proceed. That would be very helpful. I hope I provided enough information.

Comment: Are you sure you’ve got `Colour` and `Celltype` the correct way round in your desired output?

Comment: Yes, what makes you think otherwise? :) basically I want all combinations of Sample (A/B) Celltype (1/2) and colour (green/red).

Comment: Because, in your desired output, the `Celltype` coilumn contains values `"red"` and `"green"`, which are names of colours and  the `Colour` column contains values `"Cells1"` and `"Cells2"`, which could well be cell types.

Comment: Oh.. true! Of course, thank you :) I changed it

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to first get rid of the first row and use `pivot_longer` like so:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

reprex |> 
  slice(-1) |> 
  pivot_longer(-Sample, names_to = c("Celltype", "Colour"), 
               names_pattern = "^(.*\\d)(.*)$", values_to = "Signal")
#> # A tibble: 8 × 4
#>   Sample Celltype Colour Signal
#>   <chr>  <chr>    <chr>  <chr> 
#> 1 A      cells1   green  3917  
#> 2 A      cells1   red    267   
#> 3 A      cells2   green  4443  
#> 4 A      cells2   red    1438  
#> 5 B      cells1   green  4370  
#> 6 B      cells1   red    299   
#> 7 B      cells2   green  7082  
#> 8 B      cells2   red    1694
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very cool :) I needed some extra reading because I'm not very familiar with regular expressions and so on. So in case anyone in my position comes across this, here are some explanations (please correct me if they are wrong :D):

1. '|>' is a base R pipe, similar to '%>%' but doesn't need any packages to be used. I didn't know this pipe

Comment: 2. when you write more than one variable in 'names_to' (in this case "Celltype" and "Colour"), you have to specify which part of the column names goes where -> By 'names_pattern =' and this regular expression '"^(.*\\d)(.*)$"'. 
The part between the first brackets (.*\\d) goes into the first column and the part between the second brackets (.*) goes into the second column.
1st column: '^' means at the beginning and (.*\\d) "any character [.], 0 or more times, followed by any digit (1x)
2nd column: (.*) means "any character [.], 0 or more times, which is at the end [$] of the name

Comment: Hi @sirpbele. You got everything right and explained it correctly. (: